# Dynamic Pivot - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I have a test SQL database the following query:

```html
USE DataBase1

Select Data.MonthDate,
  Data.AccountID,
  Data.MonthID,
  Data.Sales,
  Data.AccountName
From Test1 as Data with(nolock)
```

That I need to pivot based off of the sales column. The problem is the months when I run this query will always change (though there will always be 4 of them) and they need to be ordered left-to-right/oldest-newest in the pivoted result based off of the MonthDate column. The initial return when the query is run looks like this:

[image]

And the final result needs to look like this:

[image]

I'm using Excel here to demonstrate and I highlighted the 0's because those are technically NULL values but I need them to come back as 0.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and the actual database I'll be running this against is over 200,000 rows.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Joshua

Comment: can you create a sql fiddle with all this test data?

Comment: Have you tried anything by writing sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Dynamic Query`.

```
DECLARE @col_list VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sel_list VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql      NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT DISTINCT @col_list += '[' + Isnull(MonthID, '') + '],'
FROM   Test1
ORDER  BY MonthID

SELECT @col_list = LEFT(@col_list, Len(@col_list) - 1)

SELECT DISTINCT @sel_list += 'Isnull([' + Isnull(MonthID, '') + '],0) ' + '['+ MonthID + '],'
FROM   Test1
ORDER  BY MonthID

SELECT @sel_list = LEFT(@sel_list, Len(@sel_list) - 1)

SET @sql ='select Data.AccountID,Data.AccountName,'+ @sel_list+ ' from (
                Select
                Data.AccountID,
                Data.MonthID,
                Data.Sales,
                Data.AccountName
                From Test1 as Data ) A
                pivot (sum(Sales) for monthid in('+ @col_list + ')) piv'

--PRINT @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to dynamically build the PIVOT query and use sp_exec to run it.
SQL Server, out of the box, has no support for dynamic ever-changing columns as the columns need to be defined in the PIVOT query.

Here's an example of how to accomplish this: http://sqlhints.com/tag/dynamic-pivot-column-names/